# Prove that $\,\int_0^1 \sqrt{1+x^2}\,\mathrm dx\le \int_0^1 \sqrt{1+x}\,\mathrm dx\,,\,$ proof verification.

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, definite-integrals, proof-writing

> Prove that $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \sqrt{1+x^2}\mathrm dx\le \int_0^1 \sqrt{1+x}\,\mathrm dx$

So these are my first days of integral calulus. I think that's well done and is all clear, but would like to know if there's a better way to work it, or even if I've omitted something, would like to know what you will add or improve, thanks!

My proof:

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{1+x^2}$ and $g(x)=\sqrt{1+x}$ continuous functions on the interval $[0,1]$, then, for both functions, the condition $x\in [0,1] \to 0\le x\le 1$ must be satisfied. So, we start by building the functions based on this condition:

$$x\in [0,1] \to 0\le x\le 1$$
$$0\le x^2\le x$$
$$1\le 1+x^2\le 1+x$$
$$1\le \sqrt{1+x^2}\le \sqrt{1+x}$$
So, that implies that:$$f(x)\le g(x), \forall x\in[0,1]$$
(For this last step, I'm just applying a known proposition: If $f(x)\ge g(x), $ then $\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm dx\ge \int_a^b g(x)\,\mathrm dx$)

$$\int_0^1 \sqrt{1+x^2}\,\mathrm dx\le \int_0^1 \sqrt{1+x}\,\mathrm dx$$

Comment: Looks fine to me! Just so you know that last proposition you used is the monotonicity of the integral and it comes up a lot in analysis. Good job!

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for such name too.

Comment: @Roma_Rayado, congratulations ! Your proof is very good. You just need to learn to use MathJax better. Click [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$\text{I}＝\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt {1＋x}\;dx＝\int_{0}^{1}\left({1＋x}\right)^{\frac {1}{2}}dx＝\left[{\frac {2\left({1＋x}\right)^{\frac {3}{2}}}{3}}\right]^1_0＝\frac {4\sqrt {2}-2}{3}\\~\\$$
Let
$$\text{J}＝\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt {1＋x^2}\;dx＝\left[{x\sqrt {1＋x^2}}\right]^1_0-\int_{0}^{1}\frac {x^2}{\sqrt {1＋x^2}}dx\\~\\＝\sqrt {2}-\int_{0}^{1}\left({\sqrt {1＋x^2}-\frac {1}{\sqrt {1＋x^2}}}\right)dx\\~\\2\text{J}＝\sqrt {2}＋\int_{0}^{1}\frac {1}{\sqrt {1＋x^2}}dx\\~\\$$
and therefore
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac {1}{\sqrt {1＋x^2}}dx＝\int_{0}^{\frac {\pi}{4}}\frac {1＋\tan^2(x)}{\sqrt {1＋\tan^2(x)}}dx＝\int_{0}^{\frac {\pi}{4}}\sec(x)\;dx＝\left[{\ln(\sec(x)＋\tan(x))}\right]^{\frac {\pi}{4}}_{0}＝\ln(1＋\sqrt {2})\\~\\$$
Finally
$$2\text{J}＝\sqrt {2}＋\ln(1＋\sqrt {2})\implies\;\text{J}＝\frac {\sqrt {2}＋\ln(1＋\sqrt {2})}{2}$$
So:$I>J$